# is there anyway i can have listarray<string,int,int> in android?

Tags: android

is there anyway i can have multi dimensional array ex: listarray string,int,int in android??
it is quite possible with Map & Set in Java/C++.

Comment: Android code _is_ java, so if you can do it java - juse use the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own container with fields good explaining its purpose:

```
class PersonData {
public int age;
public int id;
public String name }
```

And make list of it:

```
List<PersonData> dataList = new ArrayList<PersonData>();
```

Acces your fields by:

```
dataList.get(5).age = 11;
```

As Egor said in comment, a good practice will be set those field as protected and create setters and getters, if you don't need extreme performance in this specific case.

Comment: The solution is fine, only that you're not bothering yourself too much with the encapsulation principle.

Comment: This is closest to three dimensional array. If athor wants an multi dimensional array, not OO-oriented structure, there can be efficiency involved, and sush object will be fast to iterate without function calls to getters and setters.

Comment: What you're suggesting is called "premature optimization". You should always write code keeping good design principles in mind. Afterwards, when you finish coding and you see that your application isn't as quick as you've wanted it to be, you can start optimizing it to achieve a better performance.